# Sum from different columns based on criteria in Excel

Tags: excel

I have two columns in Excel, PROJECTED and ACTUAL.

```
    A           B
PROJECTED    ACTUAL
  $250.00     $0.00 <-- grab from Col A
   $60.00    $60.00
  $100.00    $90.00
  $300.00   $310.00

     TOTAL: $710.00 <-- this should be the answer (not $460)
```

I want to sum the "ACTUAL" column, so normally I would do SUM(B1:B6), but if I am missing a value (or it is 0) in any given row in the "ACTUAL" column, I want to pull from the "PROJECTED" column for that row.

The intent is to have a running total that will gradually get more accurate as money is received and entered into the "ACTUAL" column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=SUM(B1:B6)+SUMIF(B1:B6,"<=0",A1:A6)
```

Answer (score 1):

Option that works also with blank cells:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B2:B5=0)*(A2:A5)+(B2:B5))
```

[image]